# Maven dependencies for camel - spring - hibernate project

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, apache-camel

I have a camel project and I want to use Hibernate and support transactions.

I have the following dependencies and this works fine with camel hibernate component.

```
<properties>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    <camel.version>2.16.1</camel.version>
<org.springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- camel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Active MQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- use spring TX -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now, I want to add a call to a service bean in the route

```
<to uri="bean:accountService?method=findByType(2)"/>
```

and I get

**"Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread"**

I tried adding **`<tx:annotation-driven/>`** and added these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

So now , I'm getting :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:457)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.clearMetadataCache()V
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:205)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:154)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:124)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:343)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main(Main.java:87)
```

I think it's related to the maven dependencies. Please help me correct this.

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.10 probably uses Spring 3, not Spring 4. I think you have a conflicting version between the spring libraries. Use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see the dependency tree, and add an exclusion to the spring 3 library. More over, you should use the v5.13 of ActiveMQ

Comment: Changed spring version to 4.1.8.RELEASE (it's the one used by camel) and it's working. So it seems there's a conflict of Spring versions for some libraries I don't explicitly declare. If I want to upgrade to newer Spring , could you suggest how to find the relevant dependencies that should be overriden ?

Comment: If you use `mvn dependency:tree` you'll see which libraries has a dependency on spring and the version of the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your Question**

1. You are missing Spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar in your dependency pom.xml.
   [image: SpringBeansMissing]
2. Please use [Spring Bill of Materials](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-4.2.4.RELEASE.pom) when you are using Spring 4.X version to avoid dependency issues.